# Cannot boot on USB stick , Acer Swift 3

Tags: live-usb, acer, usb-installation, 20.04

I'm trying to run an Ubuntu live on a USB stick instead to install it after.

But the system freezes during the boot screen, with the manufacturer logo...

I've tried `nomodeset` and it still does not work.

USB live stick created with Rufus 3.10 and launch on an Acer Swift 3, Ryzen 5 3500U.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Does your Live USB stick boot on other systems? If it's locking up at the manufacturers boot logo, it's likely a hardware problem that's arising prior to the launch of the boot loader.

Answer (score 1):

I might be late to the party, but this might help people with identical problems.

I had exactly the same problem as you. Not only Ubuntu, but Lubuntu, Mint, Zorin, antiX... They all failed to live boot and hanged midway during the boot.
I checked the integrity of the ISO's, tried creating the USB media using DD, all to no avail.
I had been using previous versions of Rufus without problems for years... and that's when it hit me - All these were created using Rufus 3.10, which I hadn't used before.

Just to check, I created a live USB media using balenaEtcher and, sure enough, it worked on the first try.

Tried the other flavors too and they all worked (using the very same ISO's as before).

Something is off with Rufus 3.10...

Answer (score 0):

Unplug the sick and try again.

If your hardware freezes *without* the stick inserted, then you have a hardware issue unrelated to Ubuntu.

If your hardware freezes only when the stick is inserted, then test the stick in another machine.

If the stick fails in multiple machines, then re-download (and [verify](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu)) the .iso file, and [re-make the stick](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

If the stick fails after several careful tries, then get a new stick.

Comment: My W10 works properly so there is not hardware problem.
I have not multiple machines so I cannot try on an other but I've verified the .iso and all is fine.
Finally I've tried with several USB sticks and problem still the same.

I think problem comes from the way I create the USB live or from the BIOS. But in both I'm not an expert at all...

Comment: Well, there's a link above to the Official Way To Make A LiveUSB from Windows. Follow each step carefully, don't skip steps, and don't ignore warnings or errors. Then you will be doing it like a pro. Another option is to install a hypervisor like Virtualbox in Windows and test the .iso in a VM environment. I use VMs every day for several OS. (I run Windows 10 in a VM on an Ubuntu host)

Comment: I've followed exactly the tutorial about it. I've also tried other software, others settings but always the same problem... I'm beginning to lose hope, I so want to try and use the 20.04...

Comment: Time to try a different USB stick.

Comment: I've tried on 3 different USB stick...

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on about 2 dozen laptops recently and run into several issues getting the different machines to boot from USB.  Fiddling with the BIOS settings and forcing the boot order to have the USB disk ahead of the hard drive sometimes works.  Switching between support for legacy, uefi, both sometimes does the trick.  And I have also seen certain flash drives just not work.  You can burn the image to it but nothing will boot from it.
if the machine has a boot option where you can temp select the device you want to boot from that is always a good bet.

Comment: I have reached to boot on the USB stick but the screen freezes during boot of Ubuntu (with the logo of Ubuntu and the manufacturer), after Grub screen.

So, that should be about the legacy, uefi things but I do not really understand that notions so I will try a bit alone, if I'm a bit lucky...